# Can't add more destinations to Google Maps, using Python, Selenium in Chrome

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to add more locations to my google maps automation.
The problem is that I add one, I get the directions, I add the second one, everything works fine, and when to add the third one it overwrites on the second one that I added.
Here is the part of the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver  #automation proceess library
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\Practica\chromedriver.exe") 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/@31.4855012,74.3470166,15z") 
sleep(2) 

try: 
    frame = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="cnsw"]/iframe') 
    driver.switch_to.frame(frame) 
    driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]').click()

except NoSuchElementException:
    driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/form[2]/div/div/button/span').click()

def searchplace():
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "searchboxinput")))
    element.click()
    element.send_keys("Hotel Continental, Bulevardul Revoluției din 1989 2A, Timișoara")
    submit= driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/button")
    submit.click()
    
    sleep(3)
searchplace()

def directions():
    sleep(10)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "EgL07d")))
    element.click()  
    sleep(5)
directions()

def add_point():
    sleep(5)
    point1= driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/button/div[1]/div")
    point1.click()
    submit= driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/input")
    submit.send_keys("Căminul 22C, Aleea Studenților 6, Timișoara")
    submit= driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/button[1]")
    submit.click()
    sleep(4)
add_point()

def add_point2():
    point2= driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/button/div[1]/div")
    point2.click()
    submit= driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/input")
    submit.send_keys("Hotel Boavista, Aleea F. C. Ripensia 7/A, Timișoara 300575")
    submit= driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/button[1]")
    submit.click()
    sleep(20)
add_point2()
```

I think the problems stands in the div's, being the same.
Here are some screens to understand better:

[After running "add_point"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzPLr.png)

[After running "add_point1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyZsX.png)

Comment: Post full code please.

Comment: Done. Sorry for that ^^